# What is the most effective way of creating indexes under certain situation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, sql-tuning

OK, this is my condition and questions.. Assume that this is the only SQL we are using for tables/indexes

```
SELECT B.DIST_NM
, COUNT(+)
  FROM CUST A, DIST B
 WHERE A.COUNTRY_CD = 'USA'
   AND A.CUST_CD = B.CUST_CD
   AND A.CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM ORDS WHERE ORDER_CD = '20')
   AND A.CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUST_INFO WHERE INFO = 'N')
 GROUP BY B.DIST_NM

 ........................................

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUST WHERE A.COUNTRY_CD = 'USA' -> about half million rows
SELECT CUST_ID FROM ORDS WHERE ORDER_CD = '20' -> about 1.5 million rows
SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUST_INFO WHERE INFO = 'N' -> about 50 rows
```

1. what are the most effective of creating index for each table ?

   -CUST : COUNTRY_CD + CUST_ID

   -DIST : CUST_CD + DIST_NM

   -ORDS : CUST_ID + ORDER_CD

   -CUST_INFO : INFO  + CUST_ID

---> I think above indexes are the most effective indexes. but is there anything else I should think about?

2. Accroding to the index above what is the execution plan going to look like?
   (join orders? ways? subquery roles?, can change sql if outcome is the same )

Can you explain this to me please...
I am thinking since 
1. SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUST_INFO WHERE INFO has the least rows it should be executed for the first time, 
2. then join with CUST table, 
3. then filter with SELECT CUST_ID FROM ORDS WHERE ORDER_CD = '20' subquery output, 
4. then join with DIST table and then perform group by ...

Am I on the right track ?? Can anyone give me an advise??

Comment: Regardless of the text of the various queries you write in your optimization effort (and correlating indexes), I recommend you trace each attempt to determine which one has the best execution statistics. You will probably learn something useful that you can share with someone else.

Comment: This join syntax was made redundant in the early nineteen nineties. Please don't use it. And alias names should have a mnemonic connection to the tables they are representing (e.g. c for cust, d for dist, ci for cust_info, ...).

Comment: `COUNT(+)`? Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT d.DIST_NM, COUNT(*)
FROM CUST c JOIN
     DIST d
     ON c.CUST_CD = d.CUST_CD
WHERE c.COUNTRY_CD = 'USA' AND
      c.CUST_ID IN (SELECT o.CUST_ID FROM ORDS o WHERE o.ORDER_CD = '20')
      c.CUST_ID IN (SELECT ci.CUST_ID FROM CUST_INFO ci WHERE ci.INFO = 'N')
GROUP BY d.DIST_NM;
```

I would recommend indexes on:  `CUST(COUNTRY_CD, CUST_ID, CUST_CD)`, `DIST(CUST_CD, DIST_NM)`, `ORDS(ORDER_CD, CUST_ID)` AND `CUST_INFO(INFO, CUST_ID)`.

Note the order of the keys in the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about how the DBMS may approach the task:

1. Read `ORDS`: `index idx1 on ords  (order_cd, cust_id)`
2. Read `CUST_INFO`: `index idx2 on cust_info (info, cust_id)`
3. Read `CUST`: `index idx3 on cust (country_cd, cust_id, cust_cd)` or `index idx4 on cust (cust_id, country_cd, cust_cd)`
4. Join `DIST`: `index idx5 on dist (cust_cd, dist_nm)`

Or maybe so:

1. Read `CUST`: `index idx3 on cust (country_cd, cust_id, cust_cd)` or `index idx6 on cust (country_cd, cust_cd, cust_id)`
2. Look up `ORDS`: `index idx7 on cust (cust_id, order_cd)`
3. Look up `CUST_INFO`: `index idx8 on cust_info (cust_id, info)`
4. Join `DIST`: `index idx5 on dist (cust_cd, dist_nm)`

That makes 8 indexes that may or may not be used. Create them, use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see which are used, then drop the others :-)